# excel help - transpose data into 3 columns

Tags: excel-formula, stack, transpose

i am trying to reformat some a table. the current format is

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzR7q.png)

i've tried using an array, etc but i cant figure out the 2nd column

tried some array formulas, etc but am quite lost - please help!

the end game is to get the data in this format for some index matches

Comment: if you are using Excel 2010 professional plus or later versions of excel, try this out: [Unpivot columns (Power Query)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098)

Comment: index&match works on rows just as on columns...

Answer (score 0):

Assume your "Current state" table put in E10:I13

In "What I need" cell E18, formula copied down :

```
=IF(ROW(A1)<=COUNTA(E$11:E$13)*COUNTA(F$10:I$10),INDEX(E$11:E$13,MOD(ROW(A1)-1,3)+1),"")
```

In "What I need" cell F18, formula copied down :

```
=IF(E18="","",INDEX(F$10:I$10,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/3)+1))
```

In "What I need" cell G18, formula copied down :

```
=IF(E18="","",INDEX(F$11:I$13,MATCH(E18,E$11:E$13,0),MATCH(F18,F$10:I$10,0)))
```